# LINQ to SQL distinct records

Tags: linq-to-sql

I want to get distinct records by using LINQ not on the base of Id but on other field of the table i.e. date.
The table schema is ID (Unique Identifier),date (dateTime), Desc varachar(50)

Records are like :
1st row:

```
Id 61DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15D8
date 8/1/2010
Desc Abc
```

1st row:

```
Id 61DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15D8
date 8/1/2010
Desc Abc
```

2nd row:

```
Id 61DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15B1
date 8/1/2010
Desc Abc
```

3rd row:

```
Id 61DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15D8
date 8/1/2010
Desc Xyz
```

4th row:

```
Id 61DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15D9
date 8/3/2010
Desc AAAA
```

5th row:

```
Id 51DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15D9
date 8/3/2010
Desc AAAA
```

Now what i want is distinct records on the base of date

Required result is like :

```
id 61DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15D8
date 8/1/2010
Desc Abc

Id 61DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15D9
date 8/3/2010
Desc AAAA
```

Comment: Sorry, my responder is broke. Seriously though, well-phrased questions win extra points. Yours is not one of them.

Comment: Could you add an example of your dataset and expected output?

Comment: You are not specifying the problem in enough detail.
In the first line of expected output, why should it be "Abc" and not "Xyz".  And which GUID should be chosen?

Comment: I want to get All the distinct records on the base of Date.

Suppose if i will use grouping on the base of date then first record from the group

Comment: I'm pretty sure my answer meets that requirement.

Comment: Hi Dave Barker thanks for the solution and it is working fine 
now one more think what i want is to get records in descending order (date)
if i use
var result = rows
    .GroupBy(r => r.Date) 

   .Select(group => group
       .OrderBy(row => row.ID) 
       .First()).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date);
then it returns records as these are not sorted

Comment: Hi Deve your solution really worked as per my requirement and OrderByDescending is also working well.

Thanks...... thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Heh, this is the same as my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3308314/linq-checking-for-duplicate-objects-excluding-id/3308468#3308468) from a few days ago.

You can use .Distinct with an IEqualityComparer

```
var distinctdates = from dc.MyTable.Distinct(new MyComparer());
```

A good example of an IEqualityComparer is here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx

If you check out the ProductComparer example, all you'd probably need to do is replace the "Check whether the products' properties are equal" part with the check you want to make (in your case you'd be comparing dates) and that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

```
GroupBy(row => row.DateField) 
   .Select(group => group 
       .OrderBy(row => row.AnotherColumn) 
       .First()
```

This will give you the first row for each distinct datefield value.

```
Row r1 = new Row { ID = "61DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15D8", Date = Convert.ToDateTime("08/01/10"), Desc = "Abc" };
Row r2 = new Row { ID = "61DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15B1", Date = Convert.ToDateTime("08/01/10"), Desc = "Abc" };
Row r3 = new Row { ID = "61DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15D8", Date = Convert.ToDateTime("08/01/10"), Desc = "Xyz" };
Row r4 = new Row { ID = "61DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15D9", Date = Convert.ToDateTime("08/03/10"), Desc = "AAAA" };
Row r5 = new Row { ID = "51DDF6A2-E5B7-4E88-91FE-5C63EF8E15D9", Date = Convert.ToDateTime("08/03/10"), Desc = "AAAA" };

List<Row> rows = new List<Row> { r1, r2, r3, r4, r5};

var result = rows
    .GroupBy(r => r.Date) 

    // Now we are simply selecting the first item of each subgroup. 
   .Select(group => group
       .OrderBy(row => row.ID) 
       .First());
```

Comment: Bzzzzz! Wrong answer. Read the question again.

Comment: var r = (from ..... blah blah).Distinct() 
Yes it will return distinct records but in my case all the records have unique id so all the records are distinct. What i want is to get records those have distinct date value

Comment: Could you add an example of your dataset and expected output?

Comment: Yes I have Id (Unique identifier), Date (DateTime), Descr varchar

records for first row are
id '71F039EE-4B12-40A3-B6FF-93436FD53F6B'
date 8/1/2010
Desc abc

records for second row are
id 'F130F028-2198-4FEC-B65C-1EE01DA648E0'
date 8/1/2010
Desc xyz

records for second row are
id 'D817800B-CCA2-4539-83C4-E58B997BA578'
date 8/2/2010
Desc jjjjj

.
.
.

Now i want the all the records with distinct date

Comment: Is your output 8/1/2010, 8/2/2010 as these are the distinct dates or do you only want the record 'D817800B-CCA2-4539-83C4-E58B997BA578' date 8/2/2010 Desc jjjjj returned as this has a distinct date?

Comment: I want 
'71F039EE-4B12-40A3-B6FF-93436FD53F6B', 8/1/2010 , abc
'D817800B-CCA2-4539-83C4-E58B997BA578',8/2/2010, jjjjj 
records

Comment: @munish why not add your data and the output you expect to your original question by editting it?